# Error for importing Parse SDK to my project in Xcode

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am trying to import the Parse sdk for my programming (Swift 2) and after I downloaded the Parse SDK form the Parse.com and adding all the required library to my project in Xcode I wrote

```
import Parse
```

and I got an error. Does any one know why do I receive that ? 
thanks

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: If you are using cocoapods add this pod to your podfile  pod 'Parse'

Comment: Be careful, Parse is shutting down.!

Comment: Thanks to all got it working ;) yeah unfortunately I know , but thanks for reminding anyway ;)